# Cannot resolve stripe-angular dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I'm trying to incorporate a `stripe-angular` module into my Ionic/AngularJS app.

https://github.com/gtramontina/stripe-angular

I installed the app using `npm install stripe-angular`.

Here is where I inject the dependency into my app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', 
    ['ionic','ionic.utils','stripe','google.maps','myApp.controllers','myApp.services'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, stripeProvider) { 
    stripeProvider.setPublishableKey('pk_test_APIKEY');
});
```

Without even injecting the dependency into any of my controllers or services, I am met with the following console error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: stripeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=stripeProvider
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7703:12
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11427:19
    at getService (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11555:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11582:13)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11510:37
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7950:18)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11497:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11437:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9069:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9084:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%…%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A9084%3A12)
```

This is the relevant portion of my `index.html` file:

```
<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in my dependency injection or perhaps some thing I am overlooking? Please be detailed in your answer if you can! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the directions from the [stripe-angular readme](https://github.com/gtramontina/stripe-angular) are missing a step.  The script include from their step #2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

Refers to the main script for Stripe, not the stripe-angular directive.  You were getting the error because the stripe-angular module ('stripe') is not included in this script.

To fix it, you need to first do step #1 from the readme, download stripe-angular with Bower, then **also** include a second script reference to stripe-angular.js:

```
<script src="your-bower-folder/stripe-angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: You were correct about including the script from my bower folder. However, there's also the issue that I conflated the `angular-stripe` and `stripe-angular` packages. The former uses a `stripeProvider` as a wrapper for calling functions like `setPublishableKey`.